# Вопрос про $.getScript jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Есть ajax навигация:

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
 ...

 $.getScript('all.js');
});
```

Хотел бы узнать, мой $.getScript каждый раз грузит на одну и ту же страницу много all.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждый раз после удачного GET запроса.

Comment: @Genson, а как можно проверять, если есть такой, то не грузить?

Comment: @ModaL - варианты

* вынести эту операцию из ajax запроса
* поставить флаг в виде переменной и проверять его 
* если all.js задает глобальную переменную, то проверять её.

Comment: Для начала я бы по возможности убрал бы getScript из get запроса. Проверять можно, например, так: проверять доступность метода из скрипта all.js и если он undefined, то загружать скрипт. Вот так, например, делают с jQuery: 
1. Подключают с CDN.
2. Используют fallback 
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>

Comment: @eicto, а если например загрузился all.js, потом я изменил его на all.js?1, то опять же подгрузятся 2 :(

Comment: @Modal, нет - этого не произойдет, во всех описанных мною вариантах.